# Testing react-router v4 routing with redux connected components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to verify that my routes are properly set up. As in when I have a certain URI, then the appropriate component gets loaded. Just to prevent me from mistyping a path accidentally.

Here's a sample connected page:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

export const ConnectPage = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.code}</div>;
};

export default connect(
  (state) => ({}),
  (dispatch) => ({})
)(ConnectPage);
```

Main Page:

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

const MainPage = () => (
  <LoginPage/>
);

export default MainPage;
```

Here's my routes file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import qs from 'query-string';

import MainPage from './MainPage';
import ConnectPage from './ConnectPage';

class Routes extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (<Switch>
      <Route path={'/connect/:provider'} render={(matches) => {
        const search = qs.parse(matches.location.search);

        if (search.code) {
          return <ConnectPage code={search.code}/>;
        }

        return <Redirect to={'/'}/>;

      }}/>
      <Route exact path={'/'} component={MainPage}/>
    </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

And here's my test that I'm having troubles with:

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import {MemoryRouter} from 'react-router';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import Chance from 'chance';

import Routes from './Routes';

import MainPage from './MainPage';
import ConnectPage from './ConnectPage';
import {createProvider as Provider} from 'react-redux';

const chance = new Chance();

const middlewares = [];
let mockStore;

describe('The Routes', () => {

  beforeAll(()=>{
    mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
  });

  it('loads the Main Page on /', () => {
    const component = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']} initialIndex={0}>
        <Routes store={mockStore}/>
      </MemoryRouter>

    );
    expect(component.find(MainPage).length).toBe(1);

  });

  it('redirects to the main page if no code', () => {
    const url = '/connect/someprovider';

    const component = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[url]} initialIndex={0}>
        <Routes/>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(component.find(MainPage).length).toBe(1);

  });

  it('loads the Connect Page on /connect/provider', () => {
    const code = chance.word({length: 32});
    const url = `/connect/provider?code=${code}`;

    const component = mount(
      <Provider store={mockStore}>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[url]} initialIndex={0}>
          <Routes/>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </Provider>);

    try {
      expect(component.find(ConnectPage).length).toBe(1);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Used url:', url);
      throw (e);
    }

  });

});
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the 3rd test pass. I would just want to make sure that the ConnectedPage gets put in place when it's appropriate.

In this state, I get:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
      in createProvider (created by WrapperComponent)
      in WrapperComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer in the meantime, so I'll post it here for prosperity. If you know anything better, please let me know!

Here's the revised test case:

```
  it('loads the Connect Page on /connect/provider', () => {
    const code = chance.word({length: 32});
    const url = `/connect/provider?code=${code}`;

    const component = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[url]} initialIndex={0}>
        <Routes/>
      </MemoryRouter>,
      {
        context: {
          store: mockStore()
        },
        childContextTypes: {
          store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
        }
      });

    try {
      expect(component.find(ConnectPage).length).toBe(1);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Used url:', url);
      throw (e);
    }

  });
```

Calling the `mockStore` seemed to be the main solution instead of just passing it as is in the context. I'm not sure *why* this works, but it does. I'll roll with it for now, but would love to hear some explanations so that I can learn.

Comment: So I found the error of my ways... `mockStore` is indeed a function where you need  to pass in the initial state... I'm with stoopid...